# Java: How to make a condition that is for the sides of isos. triangle but not equil. triangle

Tags: java

I recently designed a program that identify the kinds of triangle by the length of their sides.
They are equilateral triangle, isosceles triangle. I have a problem in making
different conditions for isos. and equil. triangle:

```
     if((AB==BC) ^ (BC==AC) ^ (AB==AC) && triInequality) {
     System.out.println(triCon + "ABC is an Isosceles Triangle");
     } else if(AB==BC && AB==AC && AC==BC && triInequality) {
           System.out.println(triCon + "ABC is an Equilateral Triangle");
```

Please help me! I am new in programming Java.

Thanks for your advance.

Comment: If not equilateral, and if all sides arent unequal, isosceles

Comment: Thank you! You are intelligent

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
  if (((AB == BC) && (AB != AC)) ||
      ((AB == AC) && (AB != BC)) ||
      ((BC == AC) && (BC != AB))){
 System.out.println(triCon + "ABC is Isosceles Triangle");
  }
  else if(((AB == BC) && (AB == AC))  {
     System.out.println(triCon + "ABC is an equilateral Triangle");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the three sides are equal then it is `equilateral`. If only two sides are equal then it is `isosceles`

```
 if((AB==BC) && (BC==AC)) 
 {
       System.out.println("ABC is an Equilateral Triangle");
 }
 else if(AB==BC || AB==AC || AC==BC) 
 {
       System.out.println("ABC is an Isosceles Triangle");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reorder your if else conditions that is

```
if(AB==BC && AB==AC && AC==BC && triInequality) {
           System.out.println(triCon + "ABC is an Equilateral Triangle");
} else if((AB==BC) ^ (BC==AC) ^ (AB==AC) && triInequality) {
     System.out.println(triCon + "ABC is an Isosceles Triangle");
}
```

by the way what is the variable `triInequality` ?

Comment: With `int AB, AC, BC` and `triInequality` is a **Condition**.                               `boolean triInequality = (AB + BC > AC) && (AB + AC > BC) && (BC + AC > AB)`         With **`triInequality`** , ABC can become a **triangle**

Answer (score 0):

You could make this quite a bit neater by encapsulating your side lengths in a `Triangle` class:

```
class Triangle {
    private final List<Integer> sides;
    public Triangle(int ab, int bc, int ca) {
        sides = Arrays.toList(ab, bc, ca);
    }
    private int countMatchingSides() {
        return sides.stream()
            .mapToInt(side -> Collections.frequency(sides, side))
            .max();
    }
    public boolean isEquilateral() {
        return countMatchingSides() == 3;
    }
    public boolean isIsosceles() {
        return countMatchingSides() == 2;
    }
}
```

Then you can test with:

```
Triangle tri = new Triangle(4, 5, 6);
if (tri.isEqualateral()) {
    ...
}
```

I believe implementing the `countMatchingSides` method makes your intention much more obvious and your code cleaner than the extended boolean expressions.